# Не работает show_examples в tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow

вот код:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
    
ds, info = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', with_info=True)
    
fig = tfds.show_examples(ds, info)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-86-76c7ac41500b> in <module>()
      1 ds, info = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', with_info=True)
      2 
----> 3 fig = tfds.show_examples(ds, info)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/visualization.py in show_examples(ds_info, ds, rows, cols, plot_scale, image_key)
     68     # Infer the image and label keys
     69     image_keys = [
---> 70         k for k, feature in ds_info.features.items()
     71         if isinstance(feature, features_lib.Image)
     72     ]

AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'features'
```

Начал изучать tensorflow и взял код из этой документации: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview
Не могу понять в чем проблема. Помогите решить проблему.
Код пишу в google colab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсмотрел ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63687461), похоже, это работает:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-datasets
```

Затем "перезапустить среду выполнения".

Судя по всему в датасете `mnist/3.0.0` был какой-то глюк, который исправили в `mnist/3.0.1`